# Gradle sync failed: setup project failed: RunConfigurationChecker

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

I am having this problem after installing the latest version of Android Studio and running it while building the project.
There is no problem with this project (which I have clone from the Gitleb site).
This problem is also present on any new project.

Android Studio Version 3.5
gradle version 5.4.1
OS Windows 10 1903

I've reviewed almost all of the methods on this site but unfortunately my problem wasn't resolved

the Event log is here :

```
Gradle sync failed: setup project failed: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/RunConfigurationChecker
```

Answer (score 1):

**To fix this, you need to change the build.gradle version of your project to 3.4**

Please note the image below
[image]

<sub>*Added on behalf of question asker.*</sub>